# SelectInputDate and inputFile problems in IE9

Tags: java, icefaces

I'm new to Java and IceFaces. I have a site which uses icefaces `selectInputDate()` and `inputfile` that doesn't work for any `IE9`-users other than me. The only observable difference is the fact that we are located in different countries.

Are there any other componets that do the same as the two mention above?
Or does anyone know of any `IE9` settings that could cause this?

I've researched this problem on google without any success.

Answer (score 0):

Add f:convertDatTime ass a child of selectInputDate :
`<f:convertDateTime pattern="#{dateFormat}" timeZone="#{timeZone}" locale=#{locale} />`